# Hazelcast client reconnects for every get operation

Tags: tomcat, caching, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I have used hazelcast to build a distributed cache for my web application. Everytime i do a get operation such as Cache.getInstance().getMap("myMap").get("key"). A message gets printed saying hazelcast client connecting... Hazelcast client connected

My doubts are

Is the client reconnecting for every get

Doesn't this slow down the application earlier i was using a static cache and it was much faster

I am running the hazelcast server as a Java application on local. The web app runs in a tomcat container on local

Comment: Cache.getInstance method, can you share it? It seems you are creating a new Hazelcast Client each time that method called.

Comment: Something is wrong. The client should connect once and stay connected. To find what is wrong will need more detail.

Comment: Yes i was starting the client everytime with the getInstance method now i put it inside the singleton method and it is working fine